# How to mix laravel and Vue2 router together

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-router

So In my laravel app we have a url say

`http://mywebsite.in/wfengine/search/`

Now I want to use the laravel router to work on the above link , but nothing seems to be happening.

**Router.js**

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path:'/filters',
        componenet: require('./views/filter')
    }
];


export default new VueRouter({

    routes
});
```

**App.js**

```js
`import router from './routes';

// import './core/searchableCards';


var app = new Vue({

    el:'#ep_result_1',

    router

})`
```

**HTML**

`<router-link to="/filters">Search Page</router-link>`

Now on the page which is loaded by laravel , I get following url in the browser

`http://mywebsite.in/wfengine/search/#filters`

But the template is not loading , can anyone help me out with this

According to me the Vue Router is just doing some Dom hide and show so it should not be effected by the base url right ?

Comment: What about misspelling of `componenet` in your routes in Router.js?

Answer (score 0):

Vue router mounts the components (defined in the routes array).
So if you defined a laravel routes to *wfengine/search/* for the (e.g.) *search.blade.php* there should be the `<router-view></router-view>` dom element, [as the doc says](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-view.html).

After that you should define the vue-router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

The routes variable is the routes array, the *mode* is for use the vue routing without # (http://mywebsite.in/wfengine/search/#filters -> http://mywebsite.in/wfengine/search/filters). 
After that you should register the url (wfengine/search/filters) in the web route in laravel, what is give back the search.blade.php or that "base page" what contains the `<router-view>` dom.

So 1. there should be a base php view, what contains the `<router-view>`.
2. Then register the urls in the server side what gives back the same base view. 3. Then the vue-router will decide which component should be loaded by the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `routes/web.php` file just put the below code. This tricks works for me.

```
// At the end of the file 

Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Of course you have to put a `<router-view></router-view>` into your layout or blade file.